# unordered_set<Foo> as data member of Foo?

Tags: c++, unordered-set

As the title says, I'm trying use an unordered_set containing objects of class Foo as a data member of class Foo. Is this possible in C++?

I have this code:

```
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

struct FooHash;

class Foo {
public:
    int id;
    unordered_set<Foo, FooHash> foos; // error here
    bool operator==(const Foo& foo) {
        return id == foo.id;
    }
};

struct FooHash {
    size_t operator()(const Foo& foo) const {
        return foo.id;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    unordered_set<Foo, FooHash> foos;
    return 0;
}
```

but it throws the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/unordered_set:47,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Foo, FooHash>’:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/type_traits:143:12:   required from ‘struct std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<FooHash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Foo, FooHash> >’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/type_traits:154:38:   required from ‘struct std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<FooHash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Foo, FooHash> > >’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/unordered_set.h:95:63:   required from ‘class std::unordered_set<Foo, FooHash>’
main.cpp:9:33:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:85:34: error: no match for call to ‘(const FooHash) (const Foo&)’
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/utility:70,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/unordered_set:38,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<FooHash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Foo, FooHash> > >’:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/unordered_set.h:95:63:   required from ‘class std::unordered_set<Foo, FooHash>’
main.cpp:9:33:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/type_traits:154:38: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<FooHash>, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Foo, FooHash> >’
     : public integral_constant<bool, !_Pp::value>
```

Forward declaring both classes and declaring the methods after gives these two errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/unordered_set:44:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/aligned_buffer.h: In instantiation of ‘struct __gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer<Foo>’:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:246:43:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hash_node_value_base<Foo>’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:277:12:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hash_node<Foo, true>’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1894:60:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<Foo, true> > >’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable.h:170:11:   required from ‘class std::_Hashtable<Foo, Foo, std::allocator<Foo>, std::__detail::_Identity, std::equal_to<Foo>, FooHash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true> >’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/unordered_set.h:96:18:   required from ‘class std::unordered_set<Foo, FooHash>’
main.cpp:12:37:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/aligned_buffer.h:85:34: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Foo’
     : std::aligned_storage<sizeof(_Tp), std::alignment_of<_Tp>::value>
                                  ^
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/aligned_buffer.h:85:34: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Foo’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/aligned_buffer.h: In instantiation of ‘void* __gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer<_Tp>::_M_addr() [with _Tp = Foo]’:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/aligned_buffer.h:110:41:   required from ‘_Tp* __gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer<_Tp>::_M_ptr() [with _Tp = Foo]’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:250:34:   required from ‘_Value* std::__detail::_Hash_node_value_base<_Value>::_M_valptr() [with _Value = Foo]’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1971:36:   required from ‘void std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::_M_deallocate_node(std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type*) [with _NodeAlloc = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<Foo, true> >; std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type = std::__detail::_Hash_node<Foo, true>]’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1984:22:   required from ‘void std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::_M_deallocate_nodes(std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type*) [with _NodeAlloc = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<Foo, true> >; std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::__node_type = std::__detail::_Hash_node<Foo, true>]’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable.h:1901:7:   required from ‘void std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::clear() [with _Key = Foo; _Value = Foo; _Alloc = std::allocator<Foo>; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Identity; _Equal = std::equal_to<Foo>; _H1 = FooHash; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true>]’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/hashtable.h:1227:12:   required from ‘std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::~_Hashtable() [with _Key = Foo; _Value = Foo; _Alloc = std::allocator<Foo>; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Identity; _Equal = std::equal_to<Foo>; _H1 = FooHash; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true>]’
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/unordered_set.h:126:7:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/aligned_buffer.h:99:36: error: using invalid field ‘__gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer<_Tp>::_M_storage’
         return static_cast<void*>(&_M_storage);
```

It seems containers of incomplete types aren't allowed in the standard. I want to try to use pointers, but `operator==` can't be overloaded for pointer operands. Any workarounds?

Comment: BTW, not sure it is not strictly UB to have `unordered_set` of not complete type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fully define your classes before using them as a template argument for `unordered_set`. While `Foo` can't be fully defined *during* it's own definition, but it's pointer type is. You can replace `Foo` with `unique_ptr<Foo>` quite easily to work around the issue.

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_set>

// Forward declaration
class Foo;

// Declare classes
struct FooHash {
    size_t operator()(const std::unique_ptr<Foo>& foo) const;
};

class Foo {
public:
    int id;
    std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<Foo>, FooHash> foos;
};

// Method implementations
size_t FooHash::operator()(const std::unique_ptr<Foo>& foo) const {
    return foo->id;
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot I could do the method separately. Thanks.

Comment: This throws another error. I'll add it to the original post.

Comment: Containers of incomplete types are not supported by standard c++.

Comment: @juanchopanza I see. I guess I'll use pointers. But `operator==` can't be overloaded for pointers. Do you know of any workaround for this?

Comment: @devil0150 It can be overloaded for `unique_ptr`. In any case, it's much easier to use a set of `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` rather than of `Foo*` for an owning container (which is your case). You'll have to always delete your pointers if you use `Foo*`.

Comment: Don't you have to implement operator== too? Because in your example the default operator== will compare Foo pointers, not Foo::id.

Answer (score 2):

As François Andrieux already pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42516669/7571258), an incomplete type cannot be used with std::unordered_set. He gave a possible solution using `std::unique_ptr`.

One disadvantage of using `std::unique_ptr`may be that your class now requires **explicit dynamic memory allocation** to insert into `Foo::foos`. In my opinion this is an implementation detail that should be hidden.

Another (and possibly bigger) issue may be that you **loose value semantics**, because std::unique_ptr can only be moved, not copied. You would have to implement custom copy constructor and assignment operator to get value semantics back.

Using [boost::recursive_wrapper](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/recursive_wrapper.html), there is another solution possible that **hides the pointer**. Although `boost::recursive_wrapper` was invented for `boost::variant`, it can be used in other situations where incomplete types are not allowed.

With recursive_wrapper, the Foo class becomes:

```
class Foo {
public:
    using Wrapper = boost::recursive_wrapper<Foo>;

    Foo() = default;
    explicit Foo( int id ) : id( id ) {}

    struct Hash {
        size_t operator()(const Wrapper& foo) const { return foo.get().id; }
    };

    struct KeyEqual {
        bool operator()(const Wrapper& foo1, const Wrapper& foo2) const {
            return foo1.get().id == foo2.get().id; 
        }
    };

    using Set = std::unordered_set< Wrapper, Hash, KeyEqual >;
    Set foos;
    int id = 0;
};
```

I made another change by using the 3rd template parameter *KeyEqual* of `std::unordered_set` to define equality of the key independently from `Foo::operator==`. Now `Foo::operator==` could be implemented as it should be, by comparing **all** members of Foo, not just *id*. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

To insert and find items in `Foo::foos`, you can create instances of Foo regularly without having to use dynamic memory allocation. Behind the scenes, `boost::recursive_wrapper` will allocate memory dynamically though.

The only place where you will notice that a wrapper is used, will be when you access Foo through an iterator of `Foo::Set` because then you have to call `boost::reference_wrapper::get()`. That's not worse than using `std::unique_ptr` which requires use of double indirection (i. e. `(*it)->id`).

Example usage:

```
int main() {
    Foo f1;

    // No explicit dynamic memory allocation here! 
    f1.foos.insert( Foo( 1 ) );
    f1.foos.insert( Foo( 1 ) );
    f1.foos.insert( Foo( 2 ) );

    // Value semantics are kept.
    Foo f2 = f1;

    f2.foos.erase( Foo( 1 ) );

    std::cout << "f1.size: " << f1.foos.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f2.size: " << f2.foos.size() << std::endl;

    // Find a Foo, still clean syntax.
    auto it = f1.foos.find( Foo( 2 ) );
    if( it != f1.foos.end() )
    {
        // Only when accessing Foo through the iterator we notice
        // the recursive_wrapper because we must call its get() method. 
        std::cout << "found a Foo with id: " << it->get().id << std::endl;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Full demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00d2a48106f2cc99

Comment: Here is [another implementation of recursive_wrapper](https://github.com/mapbox/variant/blob/master/include/mapbox/recursive_wrapper.hpp) which is a little bit more convenient to use because it has implicit conversion to and from the contained type.